# C# equivalent to PwdCompare

Tags: .net

I have a database where I'm storing a username and password. I'm using the PwdEncrypt function to save passwords as a varbinary(255) field.

Now, I'm needing the ability to save this information locally in an XML file and for me to do a PwdCompare in C# on the client.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with [`PWDCOMPARE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822792.aspx) but you should be able to mimic the functionality if you know what and if it uses a standard encryption algorithm.

Comment: That's the problem, its a built in Microsoft SQL function and I can't find what encryption algorithm it uses

Comment: [This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sqlsecurity/thread/70c37d6f-c088-4fdd-bfe1-8f120af0739f) indicates that the algorithm has changed over various SQL versions